# Is there any way to pass state other than context or props?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html states:

> Context is primarily used when some data needs to be accessible by *many* components at different nesting levels. Apply it sparingly because it makes component reuse more difficult.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation states:

> Note: By default, React Navigation applies optimizations to screen components to prevent unnecessary renders. Using a render callback removes those optimizations. So if you use a render callback, you'll need to ensure that you use `React.memo` or `React.PureComponent` for your screen components to avoid performance issues.

and also states:

> 1. Use React context and wrap the navigator with a context provider to pass data to the screens (recommended).
> 2. Use a render callback for the screen instead of specifying a `component` prop:

This implies in React Navigation, for performance, you really want context which destroys the re-usability. Is there a 3rd way (e.g. recoiljs or any other things that may have come about)? I am hoping to possibly get the best of both somehow.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm getting you right you want to pass props to another component without props drilling.
what i would suggest is to use the navigation hook navigate/push methods like this -

```
const navigation = useNavigation()
onPress={() => navigation.push('ScreenName',{'item': item})}
onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ScreenName',{'item': item})}
```

when item is the prop, and in the other screen you could accsess it using

```
route.params.item
```

Comment: is that a render callback?   (the hook).  I thought it said to avoid render callbacks for performance.